# DWA-160 and ar9170usb - Random Disconnects

Tags: drivers, wireless

Has anyone ever managed to make a DWA-160, or for that matter any usb wireless that relies on this driver, work without random disconnections that force you to reboot in order to regain access to your card?

Comment: I get this as well! I specifically bought a D-Link DWA-160 after I found out that my Linksys WUSB600N v2 isn't supported by Ubuntu. It worked find for about an hour or so, but then randomly disconnected. I finally gave up on wireless and went back to Ethernet :(

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution: install the `linux-backports-modules-cw-2.6.39-natty-generic` meta package. So far, I haven't experienced any disconnects.